# I have the error in CodeIgniter 4 and I am not using filters

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have the following error and I am not using filters.

> Auth filter must have a matching alias defined.
>
> `SYSTEMPATH\Filters\Filters.php at line 340.`
>
> 340             throw FilterException::forNoAlias($name);

Comment: Share the full stack trace, please.

Comment: 333 
334             $this->arguments[$name] = $params;
335         }
336 
337         if (class_exists($name)) {
338             $this->config->aliases[$name] = $name;
339         } elseif (! array_key_exists($name, $this->config->aliases)) {
340             throw FilterException::forNoAlias($name);
341         }
342 
343         $classNames = (array) $this->config->aliases[$name];
344 
345         foreach ($classNames as $className) {
346             $this->argumentsClass[$className] = $this->arguments[$name] ?? null;
347         }

Comment: please send me your email address i will share my code with you. my email address is= ihsan.gul303@gmail.com

Comment: please i need your help come to comment. steven7mwesigwa

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code.But I can still give you some soluntion.Check for filters parameter in your route like this.

change this
$routes->add('home', 'Controllers\Home', ['filter' => 'auth']);

to
$routes->add('home', 'Controllers\Home');

if no filters are used